# App Store Publication and Update Process

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I have following conditions:

We want to **change app icon** and **add screenshots**. Can it be done without upload new binary?

Currently no screenshots under 5.5" and 4.7" display when we want to upload new version of app. Do we need to upload screenshots prior to Submit for Review?

Comment: The app icon cannot be changed without creating a new binary and uploading. If your .ipa is uploaded to itunesconnect and not in "In Review" ( which comes after Submitted for Review) status you can still edit your screenshots and add  the required screenshots for 5.5 and 4.7 and submit for review again.

Comment: Ok thanks for your information! How about is it a must to upload screenshots for 5.5 and 4.7 if currently we don't have any?

Comment: the screen shot is  the manodatry for all devices

Comment: You can upload screenshot only 5.5 and use same screenshot for all other device

Just go to manage screenshot then you will find the option to use same screenshot to other device

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik thanks!

Comment: @iOSDeveloper yeah I just realized after you told me. But for 4" device, the option is to use 4.7", while 4.7" is 5.5". Can I really inherit 5.5" to all screen sizes for iPhone?

Comment: @Rendy Yes you can inherit 5.5" to all size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

App screenshots (device/size doesn't matter), app previews and app icons can **only be changed** with a new version/binary of your app.

Complete overview of all the fields and stuff you can edit in iTunes Connect is over here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH26-SW1